# How to minimize wind effect in beach tennis?

Tags: technique, beach-tennis

How is it possible to minimize wind effects playing beach tennis between two players?

I mean what positions can be suggested for the "strongest" and the "weakest" player?

Lateral wind for each players or wind blowing the back/front of the strongest player? Or another solutions?